# Tricky recursive (tail) function examples

Tags: ocaml, tail-recursion

I never liked to play with definitions , especially at interviews. 
As I know :

EDIT:

**A tail recursive function is a function which doesn't do any more computations after its recursive call.**

I think the 2nd one is not tail recursive because it doesn't make a recursive call at all , so hence not tail recursive.

But the 1st one is tail recursive even though it makes 2 recursive calls , it doesn't do anything after that , so I guess I used my definition of tail recursivness here correctly.

```
let rec func x =
    if x > 10 then x else func (func (x+1))  

let f a b = a + b
```

Comment: Please tag the language.

Comment: Please see my answer again, I've corrected it

Comment: the inner func call is not in tail position therefore func is not tail recursive

Comment: A less format definition would be that tail recursion can be expressed as goto. In `func (func (x+1))` the inner `func` can not be done as goto while the outer can. Note that in f there is no recursion but you have a tail call. `a + b` can be expressed as a goto to the `+` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of a recursive function is that of a *tail* recursive function. A recursive function is simply defined as a function that calls itself at some point in its execution. The definition also allows for functions that are indirectly recursive, i.e. they call another function that calls the original function again (where this chain can be of arbitrary length).

You are right in thinking that the second of your functions is not recursive at all. However, the first function is *not* tail recursive.

If we move this function to Scala we get;

```
@tailrec
def func(x: Int): Int = 
{
    if (x > 10) x
    else func(func(x+1))
}
```

the `@tailrec` annotation tells us if something is tail recursive. However, the compiler informs us there is a recursive call not in tail position. Namely, the inner of the two calls. A tail recursive function requires that *all* calls to the function are in a tail position, not just that the final call is in a tail position

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add tail recursive in my sentences :)

Comment: Except the first function is not tail rec.

Comment: @Drup Well, I verified in Scala that you are correct... I'll adjust my answer

Comment: You don't need to reach for Scala, it's a simple syntactic criterion which is pretty easy to see, and `[@tailcall]` is available in OCaml if you need help.